# Why do 12.04 and 12.10 run extremely slow on my PC?

Tags: wubi

I tried to install the 12.10 version, using Wubi. After running it, I could not even move the mouse, it was slow. Then I tried the 12.04 version again using Wubi, but it was the same.

The OS was very unresponsive,slow, and the internet connection just kept disconnecting by itself!

My computer info:

- Inter Pentium 4
- CPU 3.00 GHz , 2.99 GHz ,
- 504 MB of RAM
- HP 1740

Comment: probably not enough RAM. Try a lighter desktop environment like xfce. I think unity is too fat for your setup.

Comment: Another option is the "Gnome Classic" Desktop. You can install with `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` log out then back in again selecting "Gnome Classic" or "Gnome Classic (No Effects) as your desktop.

Comment: So, i'm not really good at this, but i'd try if i knew what that is... Can you tell me? Thanks!

Comment: At the login screen try using Ubuntu 2D if you are on 12.04. And also try getting some more ram. You will need 1 Gb if you want to run firefox and 2-3 tabs.

Comment: The most memory consuming part of Ubuntu (or indeed any operating system) is the graphics. Ubuntu can be run with different version of graphics renderers. The standard one is called Unity and it is packaged with regular Ubuntu. But there are others which need much less ram. Phipsalabim refered to one such lighweight release. It is called Xubuntu. Install that. You will probably find it blazingly fast on your system. Just go to Xubuntu.org to download. Hope this helps. Gd Luck

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need more RAM or a lighter desktop environment.

You could try:

- XFCE (sudo apt-get install xfce-common or sudo apt-get install
  xubuntu-desktop)
- LXDE (sudo apt-get install lxde-common or sudo    apt-get install
  lubuntu-desktop)

You could also try a tiling window manager, but these are more challenging to use and customize. They are, however, the most lightweight solution. Off the top of my head, I can name

- awesome (sudo apt-get install awesome)
- xmonad (sudo apt-get install xmonad)
- dwm (sudo apt-get install dwm)

Answer (score 1):

Try this first:

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

Then, if the above is slow, try:

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Good luck!

Comment: they are Xubunu and Lubuntu, please change the letters.

Comment: Done, sorry... Religion for some ;)

Comment: But, apart from all the conversation and all, Ubuntu 10.04 is still no.1 for 512MB laptops, hands down. You can still download it and still update it until April. I myself have a functional image and still working with it day-to-day!

Comment: I agree on that, I still use 10.04 on a laptop.